# Word 2010 Template is humongous

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I created a word template from scratch to use for reports, the file is 46MB. How can I make it smaller? Why is it so big?

Comment: The size of the file is really going to depend on what's in the file in terms of both content (things you can see: text, images, custom styles, etc) and metadata (information held in the file, about the file (title, author, etc etc)

Comment: Yes, but it is 46MB not K. How can I compress it? How can I get rid of the metadata? I have taken all the images out. but there are many custom styles and outlined numbering

Comment: other templates that I have created are no where near that large

Comment: Some metadata is non-removable but newer versions of Word have an Insspect Document feature (accessible from the Info tab of the File menu) I'm not sure how big of an impact it'll have though.

Comment: I tired it, and it wanted to remove the document properties and the headers and footers. LOL

Comment: In the question, you use 46K.  In the comment, 46M.  Which are we talking about?  How big is the document (pages)?  Does it have embedded pictures?  Embedded fonts?  Can you describe the template?

Comment: the 46,122KB is the correct size, (initially in-putted incorrectly). I have solved the problem though. I created a new template document and I imported the styles to the new document, added fields and properties, and now it is 78KB! thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

To close the loop on this question, we may never know why the file was so large, but the problem was solved by a method that is a good general solution to try for unusual problems with a template, like huge file size.  The solution that worked, as reported in the comments was to create a new template.  The styles were imported from the old template and fields and properties were added.  Various things can corrupt a template or get embedded in it.  Starting with a clean template and rebuilding it by copying specific features from the old one will generally leave the corruption behind.